# Desktop Outlook Plugin login issue - 13003 "User Identity type is not supported"

Tags: outlook, office-js

I am building outlook plugin, same code, same test account, it seems outlook.office.com works, however, the desktop version of outlook told me I have some account issue.

I followed tutorial to use "**Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync**" to try to get access token, if not, it will popup consent dialog.

When I test my desktop outlook, the result of "**Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync**" failed, it result shows error code - **13003** which is "**User Identity type is not supported**".

However, I use the same account for outlook.office.com, it can show the consent dialog.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error means you Outlook desktop thinks that you are signed in with an identity that is not either a Microsoft Account username/password or an Office 365 username/password. (For example, you might be signed in with your company's domain account in addition to being signed in with an MA and/or O365 account.) Try this on desktop Outlook: Sign out of all accounts in Office. Close all Office applications. Launch Outlook desktop. Navigate to File | Office Account. This should show a page with a Sign In button on the left. Sign in with an MA or O365 account. Then run your add-in.

Answer (score 2):

Find the answer, I need to Enable Modern Auth - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32711.exchange-online-how-to-enable-your-tenant-for-modern-authentication.aspx